# ImportError on pickle.load for object

Tags: python, object, pickle, importerror

When trying to load a file with pickle i am getting `ImportError: No module named application_mgmt`.

Strangely the same file can be loaded no problem form a different function they even both use the same get_file method and all. Also strangely i can load any of the other files from the function.

I have tried moving the functions to a different class/file. clearing and re-populating the saved file but nothing seems to work.

The Object in the saved file:

```
 class Application():

        def __init__(self,name,focus=False):
            self.name = name
            self.focus = focus

            self.prod_score = 5
            self.display_name = name
            self.color = "none"
```

Function that causes error:

```
  def check_meta_info(self, app_name):
            self.get_file("saved_meta_data")
```

File Handling Function:

```
 def get_file(self, file_name):
        path = "back/saved_data/%s" % (file_name)

        try:
            with open(path,'rb') as saved_file:
                saved_list = pickle.load(saved_file)
                saved_file.close()
                return saved_list

        except IOError:
            #stuff
```

Log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 400, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 221, in app_meta_info
  File "<stdin>", line 313, in check_meta_info
  File "<stdin>", line 358, in get_file
ImportError: No module named application_mgmt

shell returned 1
```

The Function That works but calls the same file class:

```
 def add_meta_info(self, new_application):

        new_meta = Application(new_application)  # creates obj

        saved_meta_info = self.get_file("saved_meta_data")

        for metas in saved_meta_info:
            if new_meta.name == metas.name:
                return False


        saved_meta_info.append(new_meta)
        self.save_file(saved_meta_info,"saved_meta_data")
        del new_meta
```

File Structure:

```
.
├── active_screen.glade
├── active_screen.py
├── back
│   ├── application_mgmt.py
│   ├── application_mgmt.pyc
│   ├── bash
│   │   ├── get_active_window.sh
│   │   ├── prosessScript.sh
│   │   └── test_lock.sh
│   ├── bash_schedular.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── saved_data
│   │   ├── first_time_builder.py
│   │   ├── saved_active_data
│   │   ├── saved_background_data
│   │   ├── saved_ignore_data
│   │   └── saved_meta_data          < HIM
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error log, I don't think your problem has anything to do with the pickle loading.
I don't know why he's trying to import application_mgmt - which line of get_file is the 358th ? - but ImportError could be caused by :

- Forgetting the __init__file in the **back** folder. A folder is not importable without it. Create an empty one if it's missing.
- Python path problem : To check if that's the problem, try adding this at the beginning of your get_file method.

  `import sys
  sys.path.append('/path/to/the/back/module/')`
- Circular imports : If you find any - between application_mgmt.py and another file -, try refactoring your code to avoid them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks the issue was in fact a path issue.